# Can't View what inside directory but can view file inside of that directory

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

I have directory and file in it

```
$HOME/tmp/file.txt
```

I want to make it so that I can't visualize contents inside of tmp but I can visualize contexts inside file.txt
So I make this part

```
cd $HOME
cd tmp
bash: cd: tmp: Permission denied
ls tmp
ls: cannot open directory 'tmp': Permission denied
```

Now I can't view what's inside of tmp directory (as I wanted)

But I want to access what inside of file.txt, so when I type
 `cat $HOME/tmp/file.txt`
it must show me what's inside of file.txt and not something like this:
`cat: /home/user/tmp/file.txt: Permission denied`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand how directory permissions work.

`read(r)`: Allows listing the names of entries in the directory but not entry metadata or contents.
`write(w)`: Allows adding, removing, or moving entries
`execute(x)`: Allows accessing and modifying the entry contents and metadata. In short the permission to search the directory.

So, an `execute(x)` only directory permission would be sufficient for your use case and let you achieve what you want. As for `cd` you need `r+x` or for `ls` you need the `r` permission.

Comment: Thanks this did what i wanted ```sudo chmod a-r tmp```

Comment: You don't need sudo as you already own your home directory and all contents in it unless root is the owner of tmp.